# How to construct a 2D array

Tags: 2d

Newbie here, please teach me how to construct a 2D array.I tried but i still cant get it.
Table example :
I have "a", "b","c" as column name, and 100 row number.

Comment: This is not a request forum. Include what you have tried in your question. Have you searched Google? What error's are you running into?

Comment: Here

http://bit.ly/1xFensK

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [0 => ['a', 'b', 'c'], 1 => ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2 => ['a', 'b', 'c']];
```

0, 1, 2 are rows
a, b, c are columns

Also check out array_map without the first parameter 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#example-5081